# TypeScript incorrectly defines type

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
interface Ev<K extends keyof WindowEventMap> {
  readonly name: K;
  readonly once?: boolean;
  readonly callback: (ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => void;
}

function createEventListener<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>({ name, once = false, callback }: Ev<K>): Ev<K> {
  return { name, once, callback };
}

const clickEvent = createEventListener({
  name: "click",
  callback: (ev) => console.log(ev),
});

const scrollEvent = createEventListener({
  name: "scroll",
  callback: (ev) => console.log(ev),
});

const events = [clickEvent, scrollEvent];

for (const event of events) {
  document.addEventListener(event.name, (ev) => event.callback(ev), { once: event.once });
}
```

At the end of the file, I use a loop to try to access the `callback` function of each events. However, I can't pass the correct parameters there, because TypeScript compiled them incorrectly.

What TypeScript does:

```
(property) Ev<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>.callback: (ev: MouseEvent) => void
```

**What I need:**

```
(property) Ev<K extends keyof WindowEventMap>.callback: (ev: MouseEvent | Event) => void
```

**[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcA8BpZEAekIAJgM7IDWEAngPYzIDqoxtA7hhOALJwAOAPmQBvAFDJkUCHFYgANtWQg4AWwgAuZNgDc4ydNkLktEEgD8mgEa1ac6SF0SpMk0YRw5cy4gqaAFBDomswk7Jw8-ADa2AC6AJTIALxC6LTAxLoAvqKiMACupmDAJsgIzpDhYAAywKRE0Dh4hFxklDT0TCxh6FxgvIJ+wkqqEAA0xqYoicjwcqRjpR5ePsiZmhg4AnHrWNhCYk4QYHlQICLDauMmSOPunt4IFKtZOQgmdaVywI+VSaXlEEqNTqXGggz0yjUmgARAgvo9oaM9Hdlo9-IEEslSu9bBAAHRyWgAcwC6DiSMycV0ojeIA+pDKtjkv2mZWkFR64GB9Sg4IkkI0yGhDKgTMRyKWD18yFJmKEtNIuIJxNlFKpr3eYDwnLA5GmkTh3wolXGIqZlRi1JgtCgMoVWsCvWMDEd4FICQOyFYCDyanAeJkxCBtR5pN6eIF41lSSErrAeJRUtV52ugrjeNTq3V2SAA)**

Comment: It wouldn't be type safe for the compiler to infer `(ev: MouseEvent | Event) => void`; you get the intersection [on purpose](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) here. The problem isn't that the type is "incorrect"; it's just not specific enough to be useful to you. TypeScript doesn't have support for [correlated expressions](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) as in [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/55344871/2887218). My suggestion here is just to use an assertion [like this](//tsplay.dev/WYYQ2W).

Comment: Let me know if that suggestion works for you and I can write up an answer (or possibly just link to an existing answer); if not, please elaborate about what is missing.  Good luck!

Comment: I.e. I need to "hard-code" types in a loop?

Something like that:
```ts
type EvCallback<K extends keyof WindowEventMap> = (ev: WindowEventMap[K]) => void;

for (const event of events) {
  document.addEventListener(event.name, (ev) => (event.callback as EvCallback<typeof event["name"]>)(ev), { once: event.once });
}
```

Comment: It's hard in the comments, and the link to the Playground does not fit.

Comment: @jcalz but it helped, thank you!

Can you write an answer and I'll mark it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assist in discussing this, I'm going to change your scroll event to a keyup event (as its event type is `KeyboardEvent` and not the wide `Event` which either gets absorbed by or aborbs `MouseEvent` depending on what happens):

```
const clickEvent = createEventListener({
  name: "click",
  callback: (ev: MouseEvent) => console.log(ev),
});

const keyupEvent = createEventListener({
  name: "keyup",
  callback: (ev: KeyboardEvent) => console.log(ev),
});
const events = [clickEvent, keyupEvent];
```

---

If you pick some `event` from `events`, the compiler determines that the `name` property is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the `"click"` and `"keyup"` string literal types, and it also determines that the `callback` property is a union of the `(ev: MouseEvent) => void` and the `(ev: KeyboardEvent) => void` types:

```
for (const event of events) {

  event.name // "click" | "keyup"
  event.callback // ((ev: MouseEvent) => void) | ((ev: KeyboardEvent) => void)
```

These types are *correct*.  It is true that `event.name` will either be `"click"` or `"keyup"`, and it is true that `event.callback` will either be a function that expects a `MouseEvent` or a function that expects a `KeyboardEvent`.

If you try to call `event.callback`, a union of function types, you will find that it expects its parameter to be an [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of each function's parameter types.  That is, `event.callback(x)` requires that `x` is `MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent`, meaning that it is (somehow) *both* a `MouseEvent` *and* a `KeyboardEvent`:

```
declare const m: MouseEvent;
event.callback(m); // error, not 'MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent'.
declare const k: KeyboardEvent;
event.callback(k); // error, not 'MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent'.
declare const both: MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent;
event.callback(both) // okay
```

I'm not sure if I need to explain it much here, but unions-of-functions-requiring-intersections-of-parameters is [a feature of TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and is *correct* and *type safe* behavior.  If I told you I have one function that expects a `MouseEvent` and another function that expects a `KeyboardEvent` but I forgot which is which, the only safe way you could call any of them is to pass them something which would be accepted by *both*, a `MouseEvent & KeyboardEvent`.  If you pass in a `MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent` instead, you're asking for trouble, since you could easily give the function an input it doesn't expect.

And therefore `event.callback` cannot and should not be inferred to be of type `(ev: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => void`.  So the compiler is 100% correct here, and the type you say you need would not be correct (although it will turn out to be useful).

---

The real problem here is that you are not trying to call `event.callback()` with some random parameter, but with an event type specifically related to `event.name`. While it is true that `event.name` and `event.callback` are both of a union type, these unions are *correlated* with each other.  And unfortunately, the compiler has absolutely no way to track such a correlation between them, especially in a single line of code like `document.addEventListener(event.name, (ev) => event.callback(ev), { once: event.once });`.

This is a pain point I've seen pop up again and again, and inspired me to file [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), asking for support for correlated union types.  Well, keeping track of such correlations might be prohibitively costly for the compiler, so I'm actually *wishing* for support instead of asking.  Mostly that GitHub issue is a depot for all the cases I run into where such support would be useful, and a place to list the existing workarounds.

---

By far the easiest workaround is to sacrifice type safety for convenience, and just use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to make the type of `event.callback` appear to the compiler to be whatever it has to be to allow that `document.addEventListener()` call.  Here's one way to do it:

```
type AssertedEventType = Ev<typeof events[number]["name"]>;
// type AssertedEventType = Ev<"keyup" | "click">
const assertedEvent = event as AssertedEventType;
assertedEvent.name // "click" | "keyup"
assertedEvent.callback // (ev: MouseEvent | KeyboardEvent) => void
```

The actual type of `event` is `Ev<"keyup"> | Ev<"click">`, but we will pretend that it is of type `Ev<"keyup" | "click">`.  Those are different types, and the difference is that the `callback` property of the former will expect the intersection (type safe but not useful to you) while the `callback` property of the latter will expect the union (unsafe but useful).  So we will just assert `event as AssertedEventType` and everything will just work:

```
document.addEventListener(event.name,
  (ev) => (event as AssertedEventType).callback(ev), // no error
  { once: event.once });
```

Now remember, this is not type safe.  You could just as easily write

```
document.addEventListener(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "keyup" : "click",
  (ev) => (event as AssertedEventType).callback(ev),  // no error
  { once: event.once });
```

and that would probably do bad things at runtime.  The fact that the compiler emits no error in either case is indication that you need to be careful.

---

The other workaround sacrifices convenience for type safety, by writing a lot of redundant and poorly scalable code:

```
event.name === "click" ? document.addEventListener(event.name,
  (ev) => event.callback(ev), { once: event.once }) :
  document.addEventListener(event.name,
    (ev) => event.callback(ev), { once: event.once }); // okay
```

This works because we are [discriminating the `event` union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) by its `name` property.  In each concrete case, the compiler is able to narrow `event` to a type where it can see that `event.callback` is suitable.  This is now 100% type safe and probably 0% usable because `keyof WindowEventMap` has something like 120 union members and you'd need to check each one.  Blagh.

---

So that's the current status.  The compiler is not wrong, it's just not helping you. There's a feature request to do something about it, but in the meantime (which might be forever) you should probably use a type assertion to the type you wanted instead, and move on.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKIDcA8BpZEAekIAJgM7IDWEAngPYzIDqoxtA7hhOALJwAOAPmQBvAFDJkUCHFYgANtWQg4AWwgAuZNgDc4ydNkLktEEgD8mgEa1ac6SF0SpMk0YRw5cy4gqaAFBDomswk7Jw8-ADa2AC6AJTIALxC6LTAxLoAvqI5ojAArqZgwCbICM6Q4WAAMsCkRNA4eIRcZJQ09EwsYehcYLyCfsJKqhAANMamKInI8HKk42UeXj7ImZoYOAJxG1jYQmJOEGD5UCAiI2oTJkgT7p7eCBRrWTkIJvVlcsBPVUllFQgVVq9S40CGemUak0ACIEN8njCxnp7isnv5AppuLR8gsqglkmUPrYIAA6OS0ADmAXQcWRmTiulE7xAnyo1HyfD+M3K0kqvXAIIaUAhEihGmQMPZnKRKOWj18yBpmmwNGscCgxHxSSELNIJPJVJpdNEDKZerAeAFYHIM0i8J+FCqE2lXOtMSZxAg8I1KAtyBUWJxeOtui9PqkRNZlsVquo6s1VTD3rkvqjn2sYAAFkHcUDrcgAGRaNW0DVa0M5GC0KBK-2BPrGBgN8CkBJiPQtsCk8XIAD0fclDsRyAAPpLXTDO9bSaiFf3B35lchsXntYTUukEuOl5iS-Gy4nrQSUmliHFp31Z-KfH4VIyF3goFAaxMQLRLQByVchxvFuMJhWfSfqSl7gNeDy3hQD4Dk+L5QGB3ZzremZZgksG0BQcDUDkEhgNQfAoAAgqQCxQJAQHgAAKgR0xoFg+GEZ0XakJEID5ColjQDEkQwuKMIxAIjiPoxxGkdAFFVDRhH-JsUo0DKY5DgiFAwgIKIfJacDieRECUZaMxdsg2nICRZGSda0kQEyEjaeZelVD2oyPnCKkwkp8kcnwU62TpFlXshTyPsuP75o244AYe+knsgm7EHorAIBxV4yPpQpgiKXZOVcegSMaOpKkZJlmRJDmWbRcQQWiFDGhMww3BKWUNWsjK4cgiXJeBqXAnUwp+Lw2aklAcChCofgJJgyAAAykgArMgZgTgp3nILCw6qciEh5YEMU0o2xV+WVfRWZVgU1TtdWTEgmhNVMLU2VaV69okL3KY67mLR1ahdcQaW9Rle3geKm1bflhJZWdtUXA1N0zs1DKrbl7W0El33dt11rpSA4JZcDSPbbSBUQzeTxQ-VUyw1e8MwYOmHYTk2RAA)